# Rails : Issue with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an app which uses devise and cancan for authentication and authorization . Using cancan I have defined two roles  admin and operator. The admin can manage all and the operator can edit all but not destroy and the third is a normal user who can create and manage. But the code goes only to the default else block. This is my ability class and index.html

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :operator
      can :read, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

index.html

```
  <h1>Listing todos</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= todo.name %></td>
    <td><%= todo.description %></td>
    <% if can? :show, @todo %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', todo %></td>
     <% end %>
      <% if can? :update, @todo %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_path(todo) %></td>
     <% end %>
      <% if can? :destroy, @todo %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', todo, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    <% end %>  
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<% if can? :destroy, @todo %>
<%= link_to 'New Todo', new_todo_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you show what is method `role?` in `user.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your momentarily setup, your operater-permissions and your default-permissions are the same. They only have the right to read all Models, not to edit them.

```
if user.role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.role? :operator
  can :read, :all # no managing-abilities defined here
else
  can :read, :all # same abilities as operator
end
```

So, in case that your `role?`-method works correctly, your problem is not, that only the else-block gets triggered, but the operator is lacking abilities.

Comment: I've given different CRUD functions to operator  admin and the normal user but  still all the users have the same functionality which is mentioned in the default block like manage in this case if I change it to read all the users would be able to only read. The roles are being assigned using a check box and its properly being reflected in db but am still not able to figure out where am going wrong.

Comment: Sorry @AmritanshMishra, I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. The only thing I can tell you for sure is that you don't allow your operator to modify any of your models. For instance, if you call in your view `<% if can? :update, @todo %>`, it only applies to your admin, not to your operator, since he/she is only allowed to read the model.
Try to add `can :manage, Todo` to your operator-abilities and check if you get your desired result.